# FormGroup valueChange filter changed values in deep object

Tags: rxjs, angular2-forms, subscriber

I am trying to filter only changed values over `FormGroup` when I subscribe other functions to it. 
So with example, my formGroup is like

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormGroup({
        street: new FormControl(''),
        postcode: new FormControl('8000'),
        country: new FormControl(''),
        state: new FormControl(''),
    })
});
```

I have nested form with multiple fields. Now I wish to subscribe various events, over different fields. Like street has something different, a state has a different function, the country other. So I am calling subscribe on `ngInit`. It gives me the issue when it loads it calls multiple times so I used `debounceTime` to control that and make it executes after 2 mins. But then also it executes for 1 time. and gives me empty value. so I could use `skip(1)` in that case. But if I call multiple functions over multiple fields of address, I need to write separate subscribe over each field that would execute multiple times again.

**Q1.** Could I club it to single function so my valueChanges filters only changed values?

Suppose in one go I changed the city, so `data` in subscribe should return only `address.city`. I would write single function then, depending on conditions. But every time it returns whole formValues. I am expecting to filter only changed values in the form.

```
this.myForm.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(2000)
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

**Q2.** Does writing `.takeUntil(this.unsbs)` would automatically unsubscribe it like this

```
this.unsbs(){
     this.myForm.next();
     this.myForm.complete();
}
```

or I need to unsubscribe to other Subscription type variable?